# uneven spacing on axis with R

Tags: r

I have a problem in plotting uneven scale plot on x axis with R

Here is an example:

```
plot(1:100,1:100)
```

will give the equal tick space on x axis.

However, I want to show the graph with first half of space showing 1 to 10, and the left half space showing 10 to 100, so the points in the 10 to 100 more dense, and points in `1:10` are easier to see. How  to do it with R?

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an easy one-off task to complete. You'll actually need to transform to the scaled data and supply custom tick marked axes. Any reason you haven't considered simply logging the x-axis instead? (supplying the option `plot(x, y, log='x')` will do that).

What I think you've described is this:

```
xnew <- ifelse(x<10, x, x/10)
plot(xnew, y, axes=FALSE, xlab='x')
axis(1, at=c(0, 10, 20), labels=c(0, 10, 100))
axis(2)
box()
```

Comment: I saw the similar the similar graph from a cell paper (Zuqin Nie, 2012). The figure 2B showed the uneven x axis. Actually I am not in favor in drawing picture in their way. I will try log.

Answer (score 2):

You could `log` the x axis:

```
x<-1:100
y<-1:100
plot(log(x,base=10),y,axes=F)
axis(2)
axis(1,at=0:2,labels=10^(0:2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For a logarithmic axis, use:

```
plot(x,y,log="x")  ## specifies which axis to put on log scale
```

For determining how many "tick marks" to use, check

```
par()$lab
```

Default is `5,5,7`. To put more x axis labels, do

```
par(lab=c(10,5,7))
```

And for y:

```
par(lab=c(5,10,7))
```